# How to display html type saved content in html?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, interpolation

I have a data of type html which is been saved from a text editor,

```
<p style=\"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;\">
 <a href=\"https://www.xpertdox.com/disease-description/Chronic%20Kidney%20Disease\" style=\"background-color: transparent;\">Chronic kidney disease</a>, 
<p>also known as chronic kidney failure, is a condition characterized by gradual loss of kidney function and affects around 26 million adults in the United States.
The kidneys are supposed to filter excess fluid and waste from the blood which is then excreted in the urine via the bladder.</p>
```

While displaying we use

```
ng-bind-html
```

in angular js but I am using a static html pages(AMP).Therefore how can I display this content in a plain html.Can any one please help me.
In amp I have only have scope to use interpolation({{}}).Can anyone please suggest me help.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> **ng-bind-html** need to get codes as `Html`, for that we use `$sce.trustAsHtml()`, *see the sample*

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", [
  "$scope", "$sce",
  function($scope, $sce) {
    var html = "<p style=\"font-size: 14px;text-align: justify;\">" +
      "<a href=\"https://www.xpertdox.com/disease-description/Chronic%20Kidney%20Disease\" style=\"background-color: transparent;\">Chronic kidney disease</a>, " +
      "<p>also known as chronic kidney failure, is a condition characterized by gradual loss of kidney function and affects around 26 million adults in the United States." +
      "The kidneys are supposed to filter excess fluid and waste from the blood which is then excreted in the urine via the bladder.</p>";

    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    $scope.content2 = html;
  }
]);


app.filter("trustAsHtml", function($sce) {
  return function(html) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <h1>convert to Html from controller</h1>
  <div ng-bind-html="content"></div>
  <h1>convert to Html with filter</h1>
  <div ng-bind-html="content2 | trustAsHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Maher I am using node js.